# Question of royal proportions

Tags: knowledge, wordplay, computer-puzzle

This is my first attempt at one of these puzzles.

The following piece of code relates to a famous saying/phrase/article/piece.

```
public void main(){
    try{
        if (this is realLife | this is fantasy){
            int i = 1 / 0;
        }
    } catch (rockFall as Excption){
        escape = !reality;
    }
    String[] files = {"i","i","i"};
    foreach(String file In files){
        File.open("user\" + file + ".gif");
    }
}
```

Solve the puzzle.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looks like

> some of the lyrics to Bohemian Rhapsody

```
    if (this is realLife | this is fantasy){
```

> is this the real life?  is this just fantasy?

```
        int i = 1 / 0;
    }
} catch (rockFall as Excption){
    escape = !reality;
}
```

> caught in a landslide, no escape from reality

```
String[] files = {"i","i","i"};
foreach(String file In files){
    File.open("user\" + file + ".gif");
```

> open your eyes (i's)

Comment: I knew i had made it too easy when i wrote it. Well Done :)